NSHostingView inside table cell view isn't automatically updating row height
When adding a constraint NSHostingController view to a table cell view, the row height isn't automatically adjusted to fit the SwiftUI views content thought I activated usesAutomaticRowHeights on my table view.
The same code works perfectly fine on UIKit.
class HostingCell<Content>: NSTableCellView where Content: View {
    
    let hostingController = NSHostingController<Content?>(rootView: nil)
    
    public override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        
        hostingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(hostingController.view)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            hostingController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            hostingController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            hostingController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    public func configure(_ view: Content) {
        hostingController.rootView = view
        hostingController.view.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
}

When I now e.g. use the following SwiftUI view for the hosting cell, the row height should be automatically resized to fit the text:
struct TitleView: View {
    let title: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(title)
            .lineLimit(nil)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
    }
}

Why isn't the table view row height adjusted?
On a side note:
NSHostingController can calculate the right height using the bounds width of the table cell:
hostingController.sizeThatFits(in: CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude).height
